# Why did I fail this audit?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

I recently started working on the review queues on Stack Overflow. I think I am slowly getting the hang of it - however, it seems that I am banned from reviewing right now.

I would like to understand what I did wrong so I can improve myself in the future.

This is the link to the failed audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15849263

Being new to the review system, I would like to get some input on why I failed that one - so that I can get it right in the future. I have put some thought into that one, because:

The audit was about an answer, but I had issues with the question: In the title of the question, it was about the green line in the screenshot, in the body of the text, it was more like a "Why does my hover declaration not work?" I was unsure if the answer was inherently bad because it addressed only the question about the green line.

Then I was unsure about the answer. Sure, it was short and did not have any additional information, but assuming that it was correct (which I do not know), it looked like an okay answer to me - sometimes answers are as simple as that.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

From my point of view, this could also be a bug, because:

- I was last working on the queues five days ago, without any indication of a ban, so I am surprised to see it in effect now.
- The system tells me that I failed the audit two days ago, which I am pretty sure did not happen, as I stopped reviewing five days ago.
- To my recollection, the failed audit was part of a ban that happened a few days ago, which was lifted.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I have now updated the link!

Comment: You last failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15849263) on the 15th, for which you received a 4 day review ban. That ban is still in effect. You seem to mis-remember when you last reviewed, as you appear to be describing the right audit. So, not a bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for looking it up! I know that I was not reviewing on Friday, Sunday and Monday, but was not sure about Saturday, which was then the culprit. It seems also that I found an explanation for why it said "2 days ago": When I checked this morning (before 10:16 my timezone), the date was less than 3 days ago. Now the page displays the correct date.

Comment: I'm not sure why that post was deleted; I've pinged the moderator that handled the flag. It's not a great audit, the post indeed addresses the title of the question.

Comment: My bad @Philipp, that answer was flagged for deletion. I spent some time looking at that and the other answer. The answer looked like a clarification of the OPs post to me (that the line indicated some style). I've undeleted it and hence it'll not be used as an audit. Sorry for the goof up.

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao for looking into it!